# AngularJS set variable do ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I'm trying to make a simple show/hide feature, but I need to first DIV open "show" how can i do that?

```
<button ng-click="addClient = true;addClient1 = false;">Client</button>
<button ng-click="addClient1 = true;addClient = false;">Client1</button>

<div ng-show="addClient">Client</div>
<div ng-show="addClient1">Cliente1</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tyq38/

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish? Do you want the first div shown by default? As it stands, what you have should work fine but both would be hidden by default until you click one of the buttons.

Comment: Where is the controller, where is the scope? I think you are not exactly sure how angular works

Comment: Your jsfiddle isn't working because you don't have ng-app to bootstrap angular so it's never running. Adding ng-app to the first div will make it work correctly.

Comment: Is that hard to write a method in the controller to update the variables?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ng-init` for that.

From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the
>   current scope.

```
<div ng-init="addClient = true">
    <button ng-click="addClient = !addClient; addClient1 = !addClient1">Client</button>
    <button ng-click="addClient1 = !addClient1; addClient = !addClient; ">Client1</button>

    <div ng-show="addClient">Client</div>
    <div ng-show="addClient1">Cliente1</div>
</div>
```

### Better Alternative

As pointed out in the comment, you could instead of using a function to toggle these settings in a controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.addClient = true;
    $scope.addClient1 = false;

    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.addClient = !$scope.addClient;
        $scope.addClient1 = !$scope.addClient1;
    };
}
```

and change the html markup like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Client</button>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Client1</button>

    <div ng-show="addClient">Client</div>
    <div ng-show="addClient1">Cliente1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though it may answer the question This is encouraging a bad development practice. The correct is to write a method in the controller

Comment: This is correct @Dalorzo, however, this answers exactly the asked question.

Comment: Angular is an MVVM Framework the layer separation should be part of the solutions regardless of some misconception, from my POV

Comment: From that perspective this belongs into a directive after all.

Comment: The directive is totally unnecessary but if you do it it will be at least one step closer of a good layer separation.

Comment: I added a alternative according to your concerns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm, I will follow the instructions and use it in controller! :)